# Is there a way to create plots in R with different functions?

Tags: ggplot2, plot, graph, graphics

I wonder if it is possible to create this kind of plots with R (ideally with ggplot2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM8BI.png)

The black line is a exponential function following a equation `y = A exp(Bx^0.5 - Cx^3)`, and the straight lines are just of the form `y=b_0+b_1x`, with differents slopes and intercepts.

I know the parameters of all those equations, but I do not know how to build that plor (made in Excel) with ggplot2.

Comment: Have a look at e.g. [ggplot2::geom_function](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_function.html).

Answer (score 0):

For ggplot to work you have to put all the data of interest into a dataframe with a column denoting the category of each line- to distinguish the different colors.
Here is how I would do it (code not tested- so you may have to fiddle around with it):

```
x=1:1000
A=...
B=...
C=...
exponential_eqn_data=data.frame(y=A*exp((B*x)**0.5 - (C*x)**3),x=x,category=paste0('exponential'))
b0=...
b1=...
straight_line_data=data.frame(y=b0+b1*x,x=x,category=paste0('straight line'))

data_plot=rbind(exponential_eqn_data,straight_line_data) #put these all in one data set

#Now plot
library(ggplot2)
plot=ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y,col=category))+geom_point()+geom_line()

print(plot)

#Or if you are not working in Rstudio

png('plot.png')
print(plot)
dev.off()
#then open plot.png manually
```